# Question about Ring of Fractions

Tags: ring-theory

I am being tasked with proving the following statement:
"Let $R$ be an integral domain, let $I,J$ be ideals of $R$, and let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$, with $0 \not \in S$.
Prove that $S^{-1}(I \cap J)=S^{-1}I \cap S^{-1}J$."
I thought that this would be pretty straightforward, but I'm struggling with this.
Could anyone walk me through how a proof for this statement should look?

This is what I've tried:
"Let $\frac{a}{b} \in S^{-1}(I \cap J)$. Then $a \in I \cap J$ and $b \in S$".
Then $a$ can be written in the form $a=i$, where $i \in I$ and $J$."
I'm not sure of how elements in $I \cap J$ should look. I feel like once I have that, then I'll be fine.

Comment: Here’s a suggestion: rather than ask someone to write for you a detailed solution of the problem you have been tasked to prove, how about you tell us what you tried and why you are struggling?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my original post.

Comment: If $a\in I\cap J$, then $a\in I$. Doesn’t that mean that $\frac{a}{s}\in S^{-1}I$? And if $a\in I\cap J$, then $a\in J$... The hard part is the *other* one...

Comment: That makes sense. I proved similar statements to this earlier, and was sort of hoping that this would follow in the same vein.

Comment: This is what I have for the first containment, following your suggestions:
''Let $\frac{a}{b} \in S^{-1}(I \cap J)$.
    Then we have that $a \in I \cap J$ and $b \in S$.
    Because $a \in I \cap J$, then $a \in I$, meaning that $\frac{a}{b} \in S^{-1}I$.
    Additionally, because $a \in I \cap J$, then $a \in J$, meaning that $\frac{a}{b} \in S^{-1}J$.
Therefore, we have that $\frac{a}{b} \in S^{-1}I \cap S^{-1}J$, meaning that $S^{-1}(I \cap J) \subseteq S^{-1}I \cap S^{-1}J$."

Comment: Yes; like I said, the more difficult inclusion is the other one.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help, and I'll keep your remarks about posts on here in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the less trivial part, assume $x\in S^{-1}I\cap S^{-1}J$, so $x=\frac as=\frac bt$ with $a\in I$, $b\in J$, $s,t\in S$. From $\frac as=\frac bt$, we have $x=\frac{at}{st}=\frac{sb}{st}$ where $at=sb\in I\cap J$.